# How do i do an type OR Type. String OR Int?

Tags: cerberus

I would like to be able to allow a string or an integer in a field. How do I do this?

This is my current schema:

```
    'minSize': {'type': 'any'},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm quoting the [docs](https://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/validation-rules.html#type):

> A list of types can be used to allow different values

```
>>> v.schema = {'quotes': {'type': ['string', 'list']}}
>>> v.validate({'quotes': 'Hello world!'})
True
>>> v.validate({'quotes': ['Do not disturb my circles!', 'Heureka!']})
True
```